# How to annotate django complex queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, searchqueryset

I want to have count of usecases.

I have three models **Customer** (all users records), **Usecase** (all usecases records)  and **CustomerUsecaseAssociation** (users and subscriptions records).

I want to count the subscriptions of each usecase subscribed by users. and I want the union of two or more usecase if customers subscribed two amoung them.

**Models**

```
Class Customer(models.Model):
   customer_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)

class Usecase(models.Model):
   usecase_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)

class CustomerUsecaseAssociation(models.Mode):
   customer = models.ForignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   usecase = models.ForignKey(Usecase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Preloaded**

Customer

```
id    customer_name
1     abc
2     efg
3     hij
```

Usecase

```
id    usecase_name
1     AT
2     BT
3     CT
```

CustomerUsecaseAssociation

```
id    usecase     customer
1     1           1
2     2           1
3     2           2
4     3           3
```

**Desired Output**

```
[
  {
    "usecase_name": "AT-BT",
    "subscriptions": "1"
  },
  {
    "usecase_name": "BT",
    "subscriptions": "1"
  },
  {
    "usecase_name": "CT",
    "subscriptions": "1"
  }
]
```

**Notes**
I will highly recommend **annotation** if anyone would help me.

Comment: I think, as per your requirement, BT will have two subscriptions, not one?
{
    "usecase_name": "BT",
    "subscriptions": "2"
  },

Comment: Yes, BT and AT both two subscriptions. Which is AT-1, BT-1 union => AT-BT+1